# How to map different json with RestKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapping, restkit

Im new to Restkit and I want to use it for my iOS project.

I ran into a problem, because I get different JSON back from the server 
and I don't know how to configure my mapping with RestKit.

Here are the two types of JSON messages I can receive from the server.

1. First json message:

   ```
   {"result":"not found"}
   ```
2. Second json message:

   ```
   { "OPDRACHT": 
        { "streetnaam":"value", 
          "postalcode":"value", 
          "city":"value"
        }
   }
   ```

I've been reading in the RestKit documentation about mapping without KVC and Dynamic Object Mapping but I can't figure out how to configure the mapping for RestKit.

Anyone an idea how to configure the mapping with RestKit in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my mapping problem today. 
I changed my json output from the server in a more object structure. Now
RestKit works great with my json.